# How to use the new column name created on the same line of code in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df`

and now I do this:

```
df.groupby(['StudentID', 'Major']).size().reset_index(name='Freq')
```

In the code above, I created a new column `Freq` which calculates the *frequency* of a combination of `StudentID` and `Major`

But now I want to get the data that has `Freq` of `1 or greater` on the same line.

Eg:

```
df.groupby(['StudentID', 'Major']).size().reset_index(name='Freq')[df['Freq'] > 1]
```

which does not work since the original `df` does not have `Freq` column.

One possible way is to save the filtered value into a new DataFrame, lets say, `df2` and then filter using `df2[df2['Freq'] > 1]` but I want to know if there is a way to use it in one line of code.

Comment: `[df.groupby(['StudentID', 'Major']).size().reset_index(name='Freq')['Freq'] > 1]` Maybe something to try

Comment: I need to return the `df` but the code returns something like series

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pipe`:

```
out = (df.groupby(['StudentID', 'Major'])
         .size()
         .reset_index(name='Freq')
         .pipe(lambda x: x[x['Freq']>1]))
```

Comment: @enke @constantstranger when using `walrus` what is time/space complexity? is it the same as assigning value using `=` ? eg:  `df_new = df `

Comment: The more official name for walrus operator is [assignment expression](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/). It is just an assignment that (unlike a regular assignment such as `df_new = df`) can be embedded in a larger expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way using the walrus operator `:=`.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'StudentID' : [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3],
    'Major' : 'math,english,english,math,physics,physics,physics,math,classics'.split(',')
})
print(df)
x = (df := df.groupby(['StudentID', 'Major']).size().reset_index(name='Freq'))[df['Freq'] > 1]
print(x)
```

Output:

```
   StudentID     Major
0          1      math
1          1   english
2          1   english
3          2      math
4          2   physics
5          2   physics
6          2   physics
7          3      math
8          3  classics
   StudentID    Major  Freq
0          1  english     2
3          2  physics     3
```

Comment: That is very clever! but it still saves the value into a new `df` and `overwrite` values. but +1

Comment: Can you please clarify what you're trying to do? Calling `df.groupby().reset_index()` has already created a new DataFrame, and the walrus operator just allows us to capture it by name and use it again later in the expression when we do `df['Freq']`. We could also replace `df :=` with `temp :=` and replace `df['Freq']` with `temp['Freq']`.